# DB's last entity ID 17 is higher than 15 from model，Rebuilding the JSON file after deleting it does not work

Tags: objectbox

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qLE5.png)

JSON file deleted by mistake, @UID again, build again does not work

Answer (score 0):

If this project is still in dev:

- delete the JSON file,
- build the project to generate a new one,
- commit the JSON file to source control (e.g. Git),
- delete the app's data (or uninstall)

If already shipped:

- revert to the commit before your changes, or
- get the shipped APK/AAB and extract the MyObjectBox.java file. It has all ID/UIDs that you can use to reconstruct the JSON file.

Source: https://docs.objectbox.io/advanced/meta-model-ids-and-uids#resolving-meta-model-conflicts